# check file existance in runtime in java

Tags: java, file, timer

I want to check whether file exists at required location or not.

I am creating one text file from java e.g. abc.txt. I am going to use this file in some other program let's say a CAD program to generate a drawing. After completion of CAD process, it generates a file with some extension e.g. '.cad'. This drawing generation will take some time.

I am going to use the same '.cad' file in another program let's say an analysis software to analyse the generated drawing.

Now my problem is, I want to check whether the '.cad' file is generated or not. As the generation of .cad file takes time, without this file I can't proceed further i.e. I can't provide this file to next step (i.e. to analysis software).

So, is there any way in java, such that I can check for existence of .cad file for some time (let's say 120 seconds). And if I find the file then only proceed to next step.

I searched about the method `file.exists()` but it checks only once.

Please give me some hint. 
Thank you all in advance!

Comment: CAD drawing are usually `.dwg` files :p

Comment: Of course 'it checks only once'. It checks when you call it. If you want to check more than once, use a loop. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Use `TimerTask` and `Timer` classes to schedule check of the file presence. And in your `TimerTask` use `file.exists()` to check the file presence in the filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you could use daemon for make your task at the background, hope it be helpful friend!

```
public class DaemonFolder extends Thread {

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation") // stop();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Pulsar enter para finalizar");
    DaemonFolder daemonn= new DaemonFolder();
    Scanner finalize= new Scanner(System.in);
    finalize.nextLine();
    daemonn.stop();
    finalize.close();
    System.out.println("Programa finalizado!");
}

public DaemonFolder() {
    setDaemon(true); // Daemon threads in Java are like a service providers for other threads or objects running in the same process as the daemon thread
    start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            sleep(5000);
            if (new File("anonymous.txt").exists()){
            System.out.println("exists");
            //DO SOMETHING
            } else {
                System.out.println("not exists");
            }               
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I used thread.sleep. and it works. But can it be possible to do a check continuously and whenever it detects file, proceed to next step? so that the user doesn't required to wait for extra time.

Answer (score 0):

You could for example write a for-loop that counts from 0 to 119 and there do the exists check, if it was successful call the next step, if not call `Thread.sleep(1000)` to wait a second before the next check.

Or you could for example schedule a `TimerTask` in a `Timer` to be run each second and in the `TimerTask` do the exists check and if maximum time is elapsed abort or if check goes well do the next step and abort.

There are plenty ways to do it, these were just two of them.

Answer (score 0):

You need create cycle with your method and Thread.sleep(120000).
Snmth. like this:

```
while(true) {
  if (file.exists()) {
   break;
  } else {
   Thread.sleep(120000);
  }
}
```